# Controlling CSS Float with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am writing something similar to the JQuery UI accordion, but vertical. I have it working pretty well with one exception. When you click the third tab, it floats left and shows the required text as expected, but it moves to a position before the second tab. Making the tab order 132 rather than 123. In every other state the numbers are ok.

Any thoughts on making the float stop in the correct order

I am aware of other vertical accordions that could be used but js is one of my weaker areas, I'm doing this more for learning.

I have it saved on a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4snqy/)

My Javascript Code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#1").css("background-color","#191970");
            $("#1").css("width", "50px");
            $("#1").css("float", "left");
            $("#2").css("background-color","#191970");
            $("#2").css("width", "50px");
            $("#2").css("float", "right");
            $("#3").css("background-color","#191970");
            $("#3").css("width", "50px");
            $("#3").css("float", "right");
            $("#boxmain").css("background-color", "#CCC");
            $("#boxmain").css("width", "400px");

            $("#boxmain").text($("#onet").text());
            $('p').hide();



    $("#1").click(function() {
            $("#2").css("float", "right");
            $("#3").css("float", "right");
            $("#boxmain").effect("highlight", {color: '#DDD'}, 900);
            $("#boxmain").text($("#onet").text());
    });

    $("#2").click(function() {
            $("#2").css("float", "left");
            $("#3").css("float", "right");
            $("#boxmain").effect("highlight", {color: '#DDD'}, 900);
            $("#boxmain").text($("#twot").text());
    });

    $("#3").click(function() {
            $("#3").css("float", "left");
            $("#2").css("float", "left");
            $("#boxmain").effect("highlight", {color: '#DDD'}, 900);
            $("#boxmain").text($("#threet").text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help you simplify this quite a lot.  There's a lot to read, but you can see it working at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4snqy/21/) first if you like.  You don't need to swap about the floats, you can just swap about the different containers.
First, some CSS:

```
.accordion {
    height:200px;
    float: left;
    border:#fff solid 1px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    color:white;
    width: 50px;
    background: #191970;
}

.boxMain {
    width: 400px;
    background: #CCC;
}
```

Then HTML- notice how I use the accordion class to tidy it up:

```
<div style="height:200px;width:558px;" id="box">
    <div id="1" class="accordion">1</div>
    <div id="boxmain" class="accordion boxMain"></div>
    <div id="2" class="accordion">2</div>
    <div id="3" class="accordion">3</div>
</div>

<p id="onet">Number One Text</p>
<p id="twot">Number Two Text</p>
<p id="threet">Number Three Text</p>
```

Now the script.  I have removed all the CSS statements because it's done with CSS instead.  I'll explain the .click() method afterwards.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#boxmain").text($("#onet").text());
    $('p').hide();          

    $("#1").click(function() {
        $("#boxmain").insertAfter(this);
        $("#boxmain").effect("highlight", {color: '#DDD'}, 900);
        $("#boxmain").text($("#onet").text());
    });

    $("#2").click(function() {
        $("#boxmain").insertAfter(this);
        $("#boxmain").effect("highlight", {color: '#DDD'}, 900);
        $("#boxmain").text($("#twot").text());
    });

    $("#3").click(function() {
        $("#boxmain").insertAfter(this);
        $("#boxmain").effect("highlight", {color: '#DDD'}, 900);
        $("#boxmain").text($("#threet").text());
    });
});
```

The click method uses the concept of "this" to refer to the element that click() is running on.  In the case of `$("#1").click()` $(this) refers to #1.  Instead of trying to shuffle floats around, you move the #boxmain element around instead.

Comment: Good thinking on moving the content box rather than the float. I would've moved the css on refactor btw, this started out just me playing on notepad++ :)

Answer (score 1):

Your divs are ordered that way in the markup. You won't be able to get the effect you're going for by changing float directions. Instead you can move your `boxmain` div around. Consider this code instead :

http://jsfiddle.net/Lanny/4snqy/18/